# Create a templated nested class cpp

Tags: c++, templates, nested

There are many similar posts, but none seem to answer my problem.
I have a templated class (AvlTree), and I want to create under it a nested class AvlTree::Node.

Because the nested class is heavy, I want to define and implement it in a seperate file. But somehow, it doesn't seem to work, and some error are thrown, mainly:

error C2039: 'Node' : is not a member of 'AvlTree'

I have added both *.h file. Maybe you can help me understand the issue:

AvlTree.h

```
#ifndef AVL_TREE_H_
#define AVL_TREE_H_

#include <cstdlib>

template<class Key, class Value>
class AvlTree
{
public:
AvlTree();
~AvlTree();

int insert(Key * key, Value * value);
Value * remove(Key * key);
Value * find(Key * key);
void print();
int clear();

int getHeight();
bool isEmpty() { return _root == NULL; }

private:
class Node<Key, Value>;

typename Node<Key, Value> * _root;
int _height;
};

#endif /* AVL_TREE_H_ */
```

AvlTreeNode.h

```
#ifndef AVL_TREE_NODE_H_
#define AVL_TREE_NODE_H_

#include "AvlTree.h"

template<class Key, class Value>
class AvlTree<Key,Value>::Node
{
public:
Node(Key * key, Value * value);
~Node();

int insert(Key * key, Value * value);
Value * remove(Key * key);
Value * find(Key * key);
void print();
int clear();

Value * getValue()      { return _value;    }
int     getHeight()     { return _height;   }
int     getBalance()    { return _balance;  }

private:
Key *   _key;
Value * _value;
Node *  _left;
Node *  _right;
Node *  _parent;
int     _height;
int     _balance;

void rotateLeft();
void rotateRight();
void rotateLeftRight();
void rotateRightLeft();
};

#endif /* AVL_TREE_NODE_H_ */
```

I know there are some line of code that are completely irrelevant, but I believe the full picture is always a little bit better.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You just need `class Node;` and `Node* _root;`.

Comment: You should get an error at this line: `class Node<Key, Value>;` That's just invalid syntax. `Node` is not a template, it hasn't even been declared at that point. You can either forward declare a class or class template, but not that. It looks somewhat like an explicit instantiation, but these are not allowed in class scope.